# Access a Ruby module's method within same module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and probably don't understand something basic:

I'm trying this:

```
# lib/common_stuff.rb
module CommonStuff
  def self.common_thing
    # code
    @x = second_thing # --> should access method in same module. Doesn't work.
  end
  def self.second_thing
    # code
  end
end

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb
require 'common_stuff'
class MyController < ApplicationController
  include CommonStuff
  y = self.common_thing # accesses the Module method -> works
end
```

Error:

> NoMethodError (undefined method `second_thing' for
>   MyController:0x000000088d8990):    lib/common.rb:7:in 'common_thing'

I tried both with Module and instance methods. Also declaring only the second_thing an instance method or both methods in the Module as instance methods doesn't work.  What do I misunderstand?

** EDIT Corrections**

I realized that my mistake was to make the methods class methods (with self. prefix). Without that it actually works. Thought I tried that, but I must have been blind yesterday. So the working code is (just a constructed example - normally I wouldn't instantiate the controller of course):

```
# lib/common_stuff.rb

module CommonStuff
  def common_thing
    @x = second_thing # -->  access method in same module.  Works now too. 
  end

  def second_thing
    10
  end
end

# app/controllers/my_controller.rb


require 'common_stuff.rb'

class MyController

  include CommonStuff

  def a_class
    y = common_thing # accesses the Module method -> works
    puts y
  end
end

ctrl = MyController.new
ctrl.a_class
```

Comment: `second thing` is defined as a class method but being called as an instance method in your module.

Comment: @harishsr: there are no "class methods" in ruby. Every method is an instance method (here the instance being whatever the current `self` is)

Comment: OK; indeed, now it doesn't work anymore. I don't know what I was doing before. And in the snipped above, I forgot to write the Method definition in the MyController class - but that's not the problem. So let me ask generally: If you have two Rails controllers which both share two methods (of which the second method is used by the first one). Where would you put these two methods into? Into a module, using the hook method as shown in the answer from 7stud, or maybe into a Concern?

Comment: And this confuses further (the hook for the injection seems not necessary): http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> What do I misunderstand?

1) An `@variable` is private, so you always need to provide an accessor method to access it (or use `instance_variable_get()` to violate privacy):

```
module CommonStuff
  def common_thing
    @x = second_thing # --> should access method in same module. Doesn't work.
  end

  def second_thing
    10
  end
end


class MyController 
  include CommonStuff

  attr_accessor :x
end

obj = MyController.new
obj.common_thing
puts obj.x

--output:--
10
```

2) You can't include a module's class methods:

```
module CommonStuff
  def self.common_thing
    puts 'hello'
    @x = second_thing # --> should access method in same module. Doesn't work.
  end

  def self.second_thing
    10
  end
end

class MyController 
  include CommonStuff
end


CommonStuff.common_thing
MyController.common_thing

--output:--
hello

1.rb:21:in `<main>': undefined method `common_thing' for MyController:Class (NoMethodError)

#obj = MyController.new  
#obj.common_thing   #Same error here
```

If you want to inject some class methods into MyController, you need to rework your CommonStuff module:

```
module CommonStuff
  def self.included(includer)  #Advanced 'hook' method
    includer.extend ClassMethods
  end

  module ClassMethods
    def common_thing
      puts 'hello'
      @x = second_thing # --> should access method in same module. Doesn't work.
    end

    def second_thing
      10
    end
  end
end

class MyController 
  include CommonStuff
  y = common_thing
  puts y

  puts instance_variable_get(:@x)
end

--output:--
10
10
```

The hook method is called whenever the module is included by another class/module, and the method is passed the including class/module as an argument.

**Response to commment:**

Only a controller's *instance variables* are made available in a view, e.g.:

```
class MyController

   def do_stuff
     @x = 10  #instance variable
   end

end
```

but `@variables` created inside class methods are not the controller's instance variables:

```
class MyController

   def self.do_stuff
     @x = 10  
   end

end
```

Therefore, `@variables` created inside class methods will not be available in the view.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to instantiate a controller.

Comment: OK, the private variable will be used only in a Rail view. As far as I understand, it's right like this. Correct me if I'm wrong. I'm going to try the class injection way, which seems the one to go in my case. Thank you

Comment: @PhilippeAddor, See my response to your comment at the end of my answer.

Comment: Aha! That's a very valuable input. I wasn't aware of that little but important detail. Thank you 7stud.

Comment: I realized that I'm not trying to include Class Methods, but Instance Methods to a controller. I have now achieved my desired code reuseability by putting the two instance methods into a helper module instead of a "standard" module. That is more straight forward for me. Now I can access both outsourced methods in two different controllers where I include the helper. I'm afraid it's not best practice though...